# What is the original semantic difference between "projectile" and "missile"?

Tags: history, historical-change

Let consider context (e.g. historical recent past) where modern meaning of missile as a self-propelled  ordinance with reactive or jet engine doesn't exist.

Then its original meaning is "an object which is forcibly propelled at a target, either by hand or from a mechanical weapon" (Oxford). How it is different historically it was from projectile (if it was), which same source defines as "a missile designed to be fired from a gun" or "an object propelled through the air, especially one thrown as a weapon".

Were they full synonyms, were they used interchangeably or projectile had appeared later?

Comment: They are fairly close synonyms, in several contexts.

Comment: A projectile could be a rock shot with rubber bands, or a cannon ball from a cannon, or a clown in the circus, propelled by a seesaw.  But when I hear "missile," I think *nuclear weapon*.  That's not an answer, just a subjective comment -- hope it helps a tiny bit.

Comment: There may be some historical preference for describing long skinny pointy ones as missiles.

Comment: @aparente001 it's _very_ modern meaning, mostly post-WWII one. And a rock shot from a sling is commonly referred as a "bullet" or "pellet" , so that's another level of confusion. The bullet on its own is derived from French "small ball"  while "ball" is projectile for a ballista and in this case related to latin verb "to throw".

Comment: Well, for one thing, I've never heard of "missile vomiting".

Comment: @HotLicks then don't go to Spotify :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How it [**missile**] is different historically it was from
> **projectile**....Were they full synonyms, were they used interchangeably
> or projectile had appeared later?

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) says,

- Of **projectile** (first use *1564*) - a body projected by external force and continuing in motion by its own inertia especially : a missile for a weapon (such as a firearm)
- Of **missile** (first use *1656*) - an object (such as a weapon) thrown or projected usually so as to strike something at a distance

Apparently, the term **projectile** arrived first, and had both a broad and narrow meaning. The term **missile** arrived later, and had a comparatively broader meaning.

The terms' meanings overlap, but are not equivalent, just as with nearly all synonymous terms.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/missile) says the original sense of "missile" was "suitable for throwing", but any distinction that might once have existed between "suitable for throwing" and "thrown" seems to have been quickly lost. Both had very similar origins in Latin verbs meaning to throw out and to send.